# Typescript Discriminated Union Type of all object members

Tags: typescript

I have something like this:

```
export const MapDispatchToProps = {
    currentDateChanged,
    attendanceReceived,
    updateRecord,
    updateRecords,
};

export type ActionsType = typeof currentDateChanged | typeof attendanceReceived | typeof updateRecord | typeof updateRecords;
```

Is there a way to define discriminated union type ActionsType without repeating properties of MapDispatchToProps?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a cleaner way to do it, but it is technically possible.

```
function f<T>(o: {[key: string]: T}): T {
  return undefined!;
}

const garbage = f(MapDispatchToProps);

export type ActionsType = typeof garbage;
```

condensed (as far as I could manage):

```
const garbage = (<T>(o: {[key: string]: T}): T => undefined!)(MapDispatchToProps);

export type ActionsType = typeof garbage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export type ActionsType = typeof MapDispatchToProps[keyof typeof MapDispatchToProps];
```

*Note*: this will result in a discriminated union only if each member (each value in the `MapDispatchToProps` object) has the same property tag (e.g. `type`) with non-overlapping values. Otherwise it will be just a union